# MPI_Scatter() followed by malloc results in a segfault

Tags: c, malloc, mpi

I'm programming using MPI and C and I'm using the root rank to read data from a file then distribute it to the remaining ranks. My MPI_Scatter works fine and I print out the values to make sure they're correct (and they are). My problem is that after allocating structures, I seg fault when trying to access them from other ranks than the root rank.

```
    pr_graph * graph = malloc(sizeof(*graph));
    ....

    MPI_Scatter(verticesCountArray, 1, MPI_INT, &(graph->nvtxs), 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(edgesCountArray, 1, MPI_INT, &(graph->nedges), 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(int rank = 0; rank<numProcesses; rank++){
      if (rank == myrank){
        fprintf(stderr, "%d %d \n",graph->nvtxs, graph->nedges );
        graph->xadj = malloc((graph->nvtxs + 1) * sizeof(*graph->xadj));
        graph->nbrs = malloc(graph->nedges * sizeof(*graph->nbrs));
        // graph->xadj[graph->nvtxs] = graph->nedges;

      }
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

And my output is:

```
    2 4 
    2 4 
    2 4
```

Which is correct. But when I uncomment the commented line, I get:

```
    2 4 
    2 4 
    [phi01:07170] *** Process received signal ***
    [phi01:07170] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
    [phi01:07170] Signal code:  (128)
    [phi01:07170] Failing at address: (nil)
    [phi01:07170] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f5740503390]
    [phi01:07170] [ 1] ./pagerank[0x401188]
    [phi01:07170] [ 2] ./pagerank[0x400c73]
    [phi01:07170] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f5740149830]
    [phi01:07170] [ 4] ./pagerank[0x400ce9]
    [phi01:07170] *** End of error message ***
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 7170 on node phi01 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Which means that only rank 0 could access the structure it allocated. Can anyone point me as to why? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Plugging in any values for the two recvbuffers does NOT segfault AND prints out the correct values. It seems that the error is rooted in using MPI_Scatter().

```
    graph->nvtxs = 2;
    graph->nedges = 4;
    for(int rank = 0; rank<numProcesses; rank++){
      if (rank == myrank){
        fprintf(stderr, "%d %d \n",graph->nvtxs, graph->nedges );
        graph->xadj = malloc((graph->nvtxs + 1) * sizeof(*graph->xadj));
        graph->nbrs = malloc(graph->nedges * sizeof(*graph->nbrs));
        graph->xadj[graph->nvtxs] = graph->nedges;

      }
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve]. Otherwise it is impossible to help you debugging. It also greatly helps if you show your own effort to debug the situation.

Comment: Hello and thank you! :) This code is as minimal as I could make it. The original source code is about 500 lines. The "..." in the code is where I read the file using rank 0 and fill my two arrays (each of size numProcesses), thus I felt it's really irrelevant to include it. I've been working on this bug for 6 hours now and I finally managed to narrow down the problem to these 10 lines of code. I'm clueless as what to try next, that's why I came here :/ I've reproduced this error by plugging in any values for my two arrays without reading them from a file and I still got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. I'll post it first then try to understand why it works.

```
    pr_int * nvtxs = malloc(sizeof(pr_int));
    pr_int * nedges = malloc(sizeof(pr_int));

    MPI_Scatter(verticesCountArray, 1, MPI_INT, &(nvtxs), 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Scatter(edgesCountArray, 1, MPI_INT, &(nedges), 1, MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    graph->nvtxs = nvtxs;
    graph->nedges = nedges;
    for(int rank = 0; rank<numProcesses; rank++){
      if (rank == myrank){
        fprintf(stderr, "%d %d \n",graph->nvtxs, graph->nedges );
        graph->xadj = malloc((graph->nvtxs + 1) * sizeof(*graph->xadj));
        graph->nbrs = malloc(graph->nedges * sizeof(*graph->nbrs));
        graph->xadj[graph->nvtxs] = graph->nedges;

      }
      MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
```

I think I wasn't using actual buffers (pointers) for receiving, just regular variables. They might have been converted to pointers (address values) during the call to malloc and that's why the size of the structure might have been crazy. I'm still not sure why I was able to print the values, however, or even how rank 0 worked with no problems. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!